# How to make my first collapsible open by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like the first collapsible content to be open by default, but not sure how to achieve this. Can anyone help please?

I admit I have no idea what I'm doing so hopefully it's something very simple.

Apparently I need to add more details as my post is all code but I think I've said everything I need to say :)

```
<style><!--
.collapsible {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}


.content {
  padding: 0 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
--></style>
<button class="collapsible">Button 1</button>
<div class="content">
<p style="padding-top: 5px;">content goes here</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Button 2</button>
<div class="content">
<p style="padding-top: 5px;">content goes here</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are already toggling a class (`active`), why not set the max height on that class in the CSS instead of using JS. Then just apply the class to any HTML you want open initially?

Comment: This is rather terrible regarding usability aspects to begin with. If you don’t want to leave users of assistive technology behind, then use an implementation that sets proper ARIA attributes at least, such as for example Bootstrap’s collapsible implementation does.

Comment: did you see my answer? does it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.active` class in the `content` element and then toggle it , settings the rules in CSS

I improved your JS a bit using ES6 as well

```js
const collapsible = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (let i = 0; i < collapsible.length; i++) {
  collapsible[i].addEventListener("click", e => e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active"));
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.collapsible:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.collapsible::after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible + .content {
  max-height: 0;
}

.collapsible.active + .content {
  max-height: none
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible active">Button 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p style="padding-top: 5px;">content goes here</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Button 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p style="padding-top: 5px;">content goes here</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked! However the + on the open one hasn't changed to -, and there is a - underneath the content - any idea why this may be? Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to set the `.active` in the pseudo-element `::after` to toggle +/-, the line underneath the content is the border-bottom from `.collapsible`

Comment: I'm unsure of how to set the .active in the pseudo-element ::after to toggle +/-. The line under the "button 1" "button 2" is the border-bottom from .collapsible. The - is not that, I think it's "\2212" in content which is placing it under the content rather than toggling

Comment: @BecNolan see the updated answer to fix alll these issues

Comment: Brilliant! @dippas